# Why I can't access my model object from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
@using Demo.Models
@model Demo.Models.MyClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div>
    <h4>Details: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Age)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/jscript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert(@Model.Id);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this code:**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id)));
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything prior to the javascript is an instruction to the server.  `@Model` is a reference to the model being passed to the code that renders the view - which happens on the server.

If you want to access the ID of your model, you will have to render it somewhere on your page, most likely as a literal in JavaScript or as the value of an HTML element that you can access through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do mapping to JS.
Example:

```
<script>
var id = @Model.Id;
</script>
```

you will be able to use Javascript var id